# .htaccess Removing ampersand from URL?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ampersand

I have been banging my head against a wall for a long time trying to figure out how to get rid of the last part of some of the URL's on my site. For example, I would like to rewrite this:-

```
http://www.mysite.com/335-protective-wrapping&page=prod
```

to this

```
http://www.mysite.com/335-protective-wrapping
```

There are about 2000 URL's with &page=prod at the end of them which I need to remove. Here's some more example URL's

```
http://www.mysite.com/335-protective-wrapping&page=prod
http://www.mysite.com/455-bubble-bags&page=prod
http://www.mysite.com/150-specialist-tapes&page=prod
```

I have tried many solutions but haven't come up with anything that works.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^&]+)&page=prod$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.*)&page=prod$ http://www.mysite.com/$1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to take into account the **query part** (after the ?) of the source-URI you have to use `RewriteCond` plus `RewriteRule`, you cannot just use `RewriteRule`.
(http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)

Sorry, anubhava, that wont work for that reason.