# .htaccess - Removing the end part of a url

Tags: .htaccess

I have been trying to remove the end of a query. I have read and tried many different examples on Stackoverflow without any luck.

My url as follows:

```
www.[url].com/search?keyword=big&limitstart=0&option=com_virtuemart&view=category
```

What I am trying to strip is,

```
&limitstart=0&option=com_virtuemart&view=category"
```

ensuring to leave the `/search?keyword=big` as it is.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18084513/htaccess-removing-ampersand-from-url

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response and the link, however I have tried this and it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have been able to achieve the above by using the following code I found online and have mix-matched:

`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&limitstart=[^&]+&?&option=com_virtuemart&view=category(.*)$ [NC]`

`RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1?%1%2 [R=301,L]`

I am not certain if this is 100% correct, but it seems to work for me.

Hope this helps someone else looking for a similar solution.